# Cannot get to BIOS to Install New Lubuntu over Xubuntu on Microsoft Surface Pro 1st Gen 128GB

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu, bios

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now. When I installed the Xubuntu on my Microsoft Surface Pro it seems it has disabled the original BIOS or something. I cannot get into the BIOS with any of the function keys on startup. All I want to do is a clean install of Lubuntu to make my system a little lighter so I can do simple dev work at school.

I originally used my other PC with Kubuntu on it to create a Startup Disk with Xubuntu on the Microsd I used with my Surface pro. It was fairly easy to get Xubuntu installed but then I realized that it may perform better with Lubuntu installed fresh. I attempted to go through the identical steps I completed when I initially installed Xbuntu over Windows 10 but it doesnt seed to work that way now.

Has anyone had any experience with this or know how I can install Lubuntu over Xubuntu in this case? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Google says these are the steps to access the bios on a surface pro

1. Make sure the Surface Pro device is turned off.
2. Hold the volume-up button.
3. Press and release the power button.
4. When the Surface logo appears, release the volume-up button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark. I tried doing that several times before and for some reason the Bios does not key up when the machine starts. I'm on my way back home now and I'll give it one more shot. It worked perfect before the Ubuntu installation though.. I'll let you know in a few. Thanks again